# Is is possible to hide / show drop down values based on the access level using Spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I know it is possible to build logic in Controller where we can try to restrict the user from seeing the dropdown values by simply not adding it to the model map object before forwarding the view to the user. We have implemented it right now.
But now we are trying to explore Spring security and add it to our application.
I know spring security can intercept urls and then either block access to it or restrict access based on user privileges.
But is it possible to provide access to a page to a user but restrict him for viewing drop down values over which he does not have access using Spring Security.
Any advice and links on the spring security integration would really be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to disable all drop down elements, or just disable some of the values in the drop down element based on the privileges?

Comment: @B.K. I want to disable some of the drop down values based on the privileges

Comment: You didn't mention what view technology you're using, but the library comes with [taglibs for JSP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html). It would be up to you to use this building block to implement your desired behaviour, though.

Comment: The list of items if retrieved from backend, then can be easily handled in backend. Don't forget, anyone can change the front-end code with firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this should work but did not try it right now.

Let's say your dropdown includes plants, but the user can see either fruits, or vegetables. You can create two roles as ROLE_FRUIT and ROLE_VEGETABLE. And if your plant has a property named type, then you can add  tag to your dropdown.

The user can only see either fruits or vegetables.

```
<form:select path="plantId">
    <form:option value="0" label="--- Select ---" />
    <c:forEach var="thePlant" items="${plants}">
        <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_'+${thePlant.type})">
            <form:option value="${thePlant.plantId.toString()}"><c:out value="${thePlant.name}"/></form:option>
        </security:authorize>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```